# add audio element through DOM javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, audio

I'm trying to add an audio element that will automatically play music through DOM to javascript. Here's my code:

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.setAttribute("src", "url(little_green_bag.mp3)");
body.appendChild(audio);
```

Can someone please help me out? What did I miss out here?

Comment: Do you write `<audio src="url(little_green_bag.mp3)"></audio>` when you do it in plain HTML? I hope not!

Comment: this is javascript. I'm trying to add an audio element in javascript.

Comment: Yes. But when JavaScript works on the DOM, it should look like the HTML when you're done.

Comment: I created an audio element as a node and then set it's attribute and assigned it to the html body.

Comment: so do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, you are not understanding what I'm saying here. You set the attribute, sure, but pretend you were just writing HTML, you would write `<audio src="little_green_bag.mp3"></audio>` - see that attribute value? There's no `url()` in there. So it doesn't belong in your JavaScript version either.